# Deductions for the sets $A = \left\{(-1)^n + \frac{2}{n}:n=1,2,3,\ldots\right\}$ and $B = \{x \in \mathbf{Q}:0<x<1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

I would like to ask, if my proof and deductions for the below sets with respect to openness, closure checks out and is technically correct.

Exercise 3.2.2 from `Understanding Analysis` by Stephen Abbot.

> Let
> \begin{align*}
>  A = \left\{(-1)^n + \frac{2}{n}:n=1,2,3,\ldots\right\}
> \end{align*}
> and
> \begin{align*}
>  B = \{x:\mathbf{Q}:0<x<1\}
> \end{align*}

> Answer the following questions for each set.
> (a) What are the limit points?
> (b) Is the set open? Closed?
> (c) Does the set contain any isolated points?
> (d) Find the closure of the set.

***Proof.***

(a) Writing out a few elements of the set $A$, we have:
\begin{align*}
 A = \left\{1,2,-\frac{1}{3},\frac{5}{4},-\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{3},\ldots\right\}
\end{align*}

The points $-1$ and $1$ are the limit points of $A$. There exists a subsequence $a_{2n-1} = -1 + \frac{2}{2n-1}$ in $A$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{2n-1} = -1$ and $a_{2n-1} \ne 1$ for all $n \in \mathbf{N}$. Similarly, look at the subsequence $(a_{2n})$. $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{2n} = 1$.

Every real number in $[0,1]$ is the limit of a sequence of rational numbers in $B$. So, the closed interval $[0,1]$ is the set of all limit points of $B$.

(b) The set $A$ is open. For all $a \in A$, there exists an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $a$, $V_\epsilon(a)$ that is contained in $A$, $V_\epsilon(a) \subseteq A$.

The limit points of $A$ are not elements of the set $A$. $A$ is not closed.

The set $B$ is open. $B$ has no largest or smallest element. For every rational number $x \in B$, there exists an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $B$, that intersects $B$ and contains points other than $x$.

The set $B$ is not closed, because $B$ does not contain its limit points.

(c) Pick any point $a = (-1)^n + 2/n$. Let $\epsilon = 2(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1})$. Then, $V_\epsilon(a) \cap A = \{a\}\ \subseteq A$. So, every point in $A$ is an isolated point.

The set $B$ does not contain any isolated points.

(d) \begin{align*}
 \bar{A} &= A \cup \{-1,1\}\\
 \bar{B} &= [0,1]
\end{align*}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overall, if this were a test and I was grading your results, you'd get 6 out of 10 points.

---

For (a), you are correct.

For (b), not so much.

1. $A$ is not open. Take $a=\frac54\in A$. Then, clearly, $a+\frac\epsilon2$ is *not* a member of $A$, meaning that no neighborhood of $a$ can ever be fully included in $A$.
2. You claim that the limit points of $A$ are not elements of the set $A$. This is partially true. One of the limit points *is* an element of $A$. For the other, you should show that it is not (the proof is easy, but it should be present).
3. Similarly to 1, $B$ is also not open. For any rational number $q$ and any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an irrational number $x$ such that $|x-q|<\epsilon$.

For (c), you are again sloppy. Not every point of $A$ is an isolated point. One of them is not.

For (d), you are correct.

Comment: That's generous, I clearly overlooked the definition of an open set: $\forall a \in A$, $\exists V_\epsilon(a) \subseteq A$ (and not $V_\epsilon(a) \cap A \ne \emptyset$ !).


For (b) 2. would it suffice to argue, $\lim (-1)^{2n-1} + 2/(2n-1) = -1$ and $a_n > -1$ for all $n \in \mathbf{N}$. That is, $a_n \ne -1$ for all $n$. So, $-1$ is limit point that does not belong to $A$.

Comment: For (c), $1$ is a limit point of $A$, contained in $A$, so it is not an isolated point.

Comment: @Quasar Yes, for (b) 2., what you wrote seems sufficient. And for (c), indeed, $1$ is not an isolated point. For all other points, your proof that they are isolated is a little short, but it is correct.